# Export Postgres 9.6 text datatype using COPY command

Tags: postgresql, copy, export

I have a postgres 9.6 table that has a text column which has email content in HTML. So it has all kinds of characters in it. I need to export this and import into a Redshift database.  I tried the COPY command with various delimiters - |,~ ^ but it keeps failing as these characters are in the text datatype.
I tried CSV with enclosed quotes, but that's causing text data to span multiple lines. 
Some of the commands I ran -

-- Export from Postgres

```
psql -d messsagedb  -c "copy (SELECT body FROM messages limit 3)  to  STDOUT (DELIMITER '^')
```

-- Import in Redshift

```
COPY public.messages FROM 's3://xxx/messages_stub2.txt' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxx' delimiter '^';
```

This fails with message - Invalid Timestamp (because the body has "^" in it)

--Export from postgres using binary or csv

```
psql -d messagedb  -c "copy (SELECT body FROM messages limit 3)  to  STDOUT (format csv) "
```

-- Copy to Redshift fails with error - "Delimited value is missing end quote"

Sample data below.  When I use a CSV, the email body spans multiple lines.  So even if I my SELECT statment in the COPY has a LIMIT 1, the output generates about 50 lines

```
"86b599b2-e0fb-4f16-b026-6aedefd52e76","3266841",,"July 15th Skills Camp Update","
    <div>

                <div style=""clear: both;padding-top: 15px"">
        <table cellpadding=""1"" cellspacing=""1"" width=""100%"">
            <tbody>
<tr>
                <td>
                    <img alt="""" src=""https://www.frontrush.com//userfiles/591/email%xx.jpg"" style=""width: 933px; height: 350px;"">
<table border=""1"" cellpadding=""1"" cellspacing=""1"" style=""width: 933px;"">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td style=""text-align: center;"">
<br>
                        <span style=""font-size:72px;""><span style=""font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;""><u>Methodist University Football</u></span></span><br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <font><span style=""font-size: 48px;"">At this time, the online registration has been closed for the July 15th Camp! Walk-ups are still accepted and welcomed! We look forward to seeing you here.</span></font><br>
```

Any ideas on  rare single-byte delimiters that can be used?  Are there any other COPY options that I can use? Unfortunately, pg_dump is not an option, as I need to run a SELECT on this table.

Thanks
Murali

Comment: You seem to have left out the sample data, output, error messages, etc

Comment: Any suggestions on this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like Redshift's CSV parser is probably buggy and doesn't handle newlines properly.  You'll need to use an external tool to load the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the ASCII field separator character for this use.  Its still possible that its in there but I've found it to be less likely than any other character.

Example:
`DELIMITER E'\x1f'`